# Cursor grabbing style not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

In Safari, after clicking on an element and activating the `:active` pseudo class, the `grabbing` pointer style is applied, but once I actually move the cursor, the `text` pointer style takes over.

This happens in Safari only.

Is there any sort of work around for this?

```
.drag{
    padding: 40px;
    background: #000;
    cursor: grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.drag:active{
        cursor: grabbing;
        cursor: -moz-grabbing;
        cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9uv7xyk/2/)

Answer (score 1):

add `-webkit-user-select: none;` on the **drag:active**